# Update Settings RC_DATA

Tags: c#, exception, base64, data-conversion

I'am using the code below To Modify Some settings :

```
       public Build(String Path)
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path, Properties.Resources.App2);
                IntPtr resourcePointer = BeginUpdateResource(Path, false);
                byte[] resource = null;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                using (BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(ms))
                {
                    String Settings = Setting;
                    br.Write(Settings);
                    resource = ms.ToArray();
                }
                IntPtr handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(resource.Length);
                try
                {
                    Marshal.Copy(resource, 0, handle, resource.Length);
                    if (!UpdateResource(resourcePointer, "RT_RCDATA", "Settings", 0, handle/*handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()*/, Convert.ToUInt32(resource.Length)))
                        throw new Exception();
                    if (!EndUpdateResource(resourcePointer, false))
                        throw new Exception();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.Release(handle);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {

                return false;
            }

        }
```

And in Form Load i'am reading those settings :

```
    public static void ReadSettings()
    {
        String PlanObjects;
        IntPtr module = GetModuleHandle(null);
        IntPtr loc = FindResource(module, "Settings", "RT_RCDATA");
        IntPtr resourceAddr = LoadResource(module, loc);
        uint size = SizeofResource(module, loc);
        byte[] resource = new byte[size];
        Marshal.Copy(resourceAddr, resource, 0, resource.Length);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(resource))
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms))
        {
            PlanObjects = br.ReadString();
        }

    }
```

Now i took this application and convert it to a Bytes => Base64String , :

```
String D = ""; //Base64String of the Precedent Application
byte[] Data = Convert.FromBase64String(D);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(Data);
var programType = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Program"); // <-- if you don't know the full namespace and when it is unique.
var method = programType.GetMethod("Start", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```

if i launch ths application i get the Exception **Value cannot** be null in readsettings Method.

but if i start the application directly by Clicking on it It Works Perfectly but Start it From another application using the code above it always threw the exception value cannot be null .

**Please note that i tried to use readsettingsMethod in** `"Start"` **Method .**

Comment: Which line in ReadSettings is the exception happening on?  Also, when you say you 'launch the application' and 'start it from another application' - what do you mean exactly?  Can you explain the context difference in how you start it, because that must be the problem.

Comment: @JimW Start application from another application is to Load it from byte Array and invoke it , other is starting it by clicking on it wich it works , the first one doesnt